# Security настройка авторизации

Tags: java, spring, безопасность

Всем привет, когда добавляю эти 2 поля выделеным жирными, при запуске выдает 404 ошибку, а без них нормально открывает. Как можно добавить 2 antMatchers одновременно? Спасибо

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Конфигурируем сам Spring Security
        // Конфигурируем авторизацию
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/client_page").hasRole("CLIENT")
                .antMatchers("/auth/driver_page").hasRole("DRIVER")
                .antMatchers( "/auth/login", "/error",
                        "/auth/client", "/auth/driver").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/auth/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/process_login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
                .failureUrl("/login?error");
    }
```

Comment: а можно текстом написать про изменения?..тут ничего жирным не выделено

Comment: При запуске, т.е при открытии страницы?